# Drawing points on a canvas with Math.PI calculations

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

I'm having some math problems with drawing points on a canvas that are spaced out around a circle.
I have the radius, the spacing of each point and even the angles around the circle but the issue is I want it to start at a specified angle and end at a specified angle.

Code

```
function getPoints(x,y,radius,ticks)
{
    var spacing = Math.PI*2/ticks;
    var points = [];
    for(var i=0; i<ticks;i++)
    {
        var angle = (spacing * i)+((ticks*Math.PI)/ticks);
        var x1 = x+radius*Math.cos(angle);
        var y1 = y+radius*Math.sin(angle);
        points.push({'x':x1,'y':y1});
    } 
    return points;
}
```

I'm having difficulty figuring out the needed math.

here is also a jsFiddle of the project: http://jsfiddle.net/Keleko34/EMeG2/
to help get the idea, the degrees I want to start at are -45 and end at 225.

the current degrees it starts at is 0 and it does the entire 360. as seen above code and example :/

Comment: `((x*y)/x)` == `y`, thus `var angle = (spacing * i)+(Math.PI)`... So you are going from angle `Math.PI` to `3*Math.PI`. Probably what you want is `var angle = (spacing * i)+(startingAngle)`? Also the words labeled "angle" here are really "radians".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `spacing` value is based on 360 degrees (or `Math.PI*2` radians).

Your starting value (see the `angle` calculation) is `Math.PI` (or 180 degrees).

Your span is therefore 180 degrees to 540 degrees (`Math.PI` to `3*Math.PI` radians).

You likely need to change your `angle` calculation (which should probably be renamed to `radians`) to have a different starting angle.

You also need to modify your `spacing` calculation to be based on the number of degrees/radians of your desired arc.

Comment: I took your advice, changed the start to 135 and the end to 280 accordingly and then added this in var spacing = (obj.endDegrees*Math.PI/180) / ticks; var angle = (spacing * i)+((ticks*(obj.startDegrees*Math.PI/180))/ticks);

Comment: although it seems the large ones are not lining up correctly, I'm gonna start looking into that.

Comment: You want `spacing` to be based on the arc. The above bases on 0 to `endDegrees`, not `startDegrees` to `endDegrees`. Try `var spacing = (endDegrees - startDegrees)*Math.PI/180`. Also `var nextRadians = (spacing * i)+(startDegrees*Math.PI/180)`.

Comment: PS - I hate sticking the radian/degree calculation inline. I prefer to write and use `toRadian` and `toDegree` functions instead. And storing a `startRadians` value isn't a bad idea either (rather than recalculating the same value for every tick).

Comment: although I did use the (enddegrees-startdegrees) I still have the same issue of the large ticks not lining up correctly. so their spacing is not calculating correctly.

Comment: They look lined up to me? Perhaps you mean that you need 1 more tick at the end? `for( var i = 0; i <= ticks; ++i )` The arc should probably go all the way to the end I believe, not stop 1 tick short.

Comment: ok looked into it, it was my bad I wasn't doing the number marker function correctly. also the stopping short by not including the = in <= like you mentioned. such simple mistakes... but thank you for pointing me in the right direction! :)